# why daily cron isn't running on CentOS 6?

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have a daily cronjob set up on CentOS 6 OS which should look after the log rotation job. The file is /etc/cron.daily/logrotate and it's contents are

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

I expected that logs will be rotated as being activated by this daily cronjob but it isn't. I see no evidence that the daily cronjob is run from the log file /var/log/cron. However, the hourly jobs are run as shown by the log file.

I have added a line on /etc/crontab  file

```
# run-parts
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

but that made no change.

I have no idea why this log rotation isn't working. I would be pleased if someone can shed some light.

Comment: Is `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` executable? `ls -l /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`.

Comment: yes, it is.                                                         -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 196 Jun 22  2012 /etc/cron.daily/logrotate

Comment: Make your script verbose so you will see if it's running fine. For example, you can remove `>/dev/null 2>&1` to have `logrotate` output.

Comment: I made the change as you suggested and found some errors. I have fixed the error and now it's no longer showing any error. I will check later whether daily crons are running.

Comment: There is no evidence that your issue is due to something being wrong with cron or the running of the cron job. It could just as likely be a misconfiguration of `logrotate`, but you have not provided its configuration. We need to see `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your `logrotate` process manually:

```
logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

If it gets errors, fix them manually.

For example, maybe there is no more space available to compress the log and rotate it (in that case, delete some logs), ecc.